# Simultaneously diagonalize the regular representation of C2 (+) C2 (+) C2.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, diagonalization, cyclic-groups, direct-sum

having some trouble with this question.

For one, I don't understand how the direct sum can operate across groups, so im assuming were direct summing the regular module of these groups

Second, I don't have much clue what would be generated by this direct sum, be it a module or otherwise, and I haven't got much clue how to figure it out.

Third, I'm not entirely sure what it means to simultaneously diagonalize a module.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

I should add this is a repost of a question I posed 2 days ago which went unseen, hoping someone who can/will help will see it this time!

Comment: Given groups $(G, \ast), (H, \star)$, the direct sum or product of the two groups is the group $(G \times H, \ast \oplus \star)$, operation $(g, h)(g', h') := (g \ast g', h \star h')$ and inverse $(g, h)^{-1} = (g^{-1}, h^{-1})$.

Comment: Ah thanks that may be enough for me to figure this out, I'll take another look

Comment: Well I now know what the regular module looks like but simultaneously diagonalizing it is still a concept im not clear on, will report back if I find an explanation somewhere

Comment: I did end up finding an answer. The key insight is finding a generator for this group, then finding all possible one-dimensional representations of the group by keeping those generators in mind. From there, diagonalizing is as simple as finding the change of basis matrix, which is going to be the matrix of common eigenvectors.

Comment: Excellent. I urge you to write up your solution and post it as an answer to this question.